# CSS :checked not changing the display type

Tags: html, css, display, checked

The :checked works as it changes the background-color of the label itself, but for some reason, it's not working with display.

I'm trying to set it to display:none, to completely hide it and replace it with another image set. Therefore the white-images and black-images

The following code is everything related to the elements being changed. Using !important will not fix the issue.

Thank you in advance

```css
.productInfo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 135px;
  height: 1500px;
}

.imagesAndinfo {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  margin-left: -30px;
  width: 90vw;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 60% auto;
  height: 100%
}

.images {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 130%;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, minmax(0, 1fr));
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.images .top {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.images .mid1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.images .mid2 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 3/4;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.images .mid3 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.images .mid4 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 4/5;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 35%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.black-images .bottom {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 5/7;
}

.white-images .bottom {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 5/6;
}

.black-images {
  display: none;
}

.white-button-color,
.black-button-color {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.colors {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(2, 1fr) / repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 12%;
  max-width: 150px;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  height: 5%;
}

.colors h1 {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.white {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border-color: #a5a7aa;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.black {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  border-color: #2d2d2d;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.img:hover {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #1c1c1c;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.white-button-color:checked~.white-images+img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="productInfo">
  <p class="nav">Products / Headsets / Arctis 7</p>
  <div class="imagesAndinfo">
    <div class="images white-images">
      <img class="top img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/13/9c/139cd0b0-d085-4d96-9314-edb8438db7e6/a7_white_buy_001.jpg__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="mid1 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/b3/bd/b3bdb8b8-2400-4575-b874-8b25a808b820/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-white-hero.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="mid2 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/67/3a/673a25f8-0dbe-471b-9d5a-f21806083332/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-white-side.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="mid3 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/ba/5b/ba5b1ece-2cc0-4f6d-8adf-4d5e2ce483bd/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-white-front.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="mid4 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/f6/9b/f69b5fd1-badb-409b-8875-b3bcf9c6d90e/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-white-lay.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="bottom img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/ea/8c/ea8c5209-dff2-49f7-9d88-b39811229023/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-white-box.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="images black-images">
      <img class="top img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/59/13/591332b6-98fe-4a7b-98ce-a7048b8e0fda/a7_buy_001.jpg__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="mid1 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/99/ef/99efd867-6813-4e70-814f-a200f58f40f6/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-black-hero.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="mid2 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/3e/b5/3eb5e245-3aa0-492d-8531-9ddcaac5da92/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-black-side.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="mid3 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/92/d3/92d34281-0989-44a3-b655-8c22e2569440/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-black-front.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="mid4 img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/4a/1f/4a1f8221-51fc-4719-a99b-c62656db5227/purchase-gallery-arctis-7-2019-black-lay.png__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.png" alt="">
      <img class="bottom img" src="https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/85/97/8597c9b8-c748-4b51-b88d-5539a380a11a/a7_buy_005.jpg__1850x800_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <h1 class="title">ARCTIS 7</h1>
    <h2 class="edition">2019 Edition</h2>
    <div class="colors">
      <h1>COLOR:</h1>
      <input type="checkbox" class="white-button-color" id="white-button">
      <label class="white" for="white-button"></label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="black-button-color" id="black-button">
      <label class="black" for="black-button"></label>
    </div>
    <h2 class="price">179,99€</h2>
    <button type="button" name="button">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: There is no `.white-button-color` element in the provided code.

Comment: .white-button-color:checked + .white-images+img {
      display: none;
    }

Comment: please mention the checkbox

Comment: Your selector is wrong; the `~` (tilde character, the [subsequent-sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#general-sibling-combinators)) will only select sibling elements, and only those siblings that occur later in the document. What you want, given that HTML is currently impossible with CSS.

Comment: So if I wanted to change the images, either change their source or get white-images' display to none and black images' to grid, I'd have to use JS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this calss:

```
.white-button-color:checked~.white-images+img {
  display: none;
}
```

to this:

```
.img:checked{
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: How could an `img` be checked?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do with css, you can't "look-up", so to speak. You can only "look-down". You can't try to select an element that's way up in the DOM tree.

If it's absolutely necessary for you to do what you're trying to do, you can re-order the items in the DOM and then use `flex-direction` to change the visual hierarchy